# Change PHP tags with shell command

Tags: php, sed, gnu-findutils

my problem is this:
I try to change all tags (`<?` to `<php?`) in several scripts with following command:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/<? /<?php /g'
```

The problem is that if I have a label like this `<?echo'Ble bla..';` ignores it and does not change. 
I recommend doing?

Comment: @André First, I was also about to answer this. But then I thought there might be some templates, ending with `*.php` and having something like `<?xml` in them.

Comment: @hek2mgl that's the author's problem, I guess he may take a quick look at what files got modified and see if any of them have such syntax, but since he didn't mention anything about this I posted that. Anyway you posted a better answer. :)

Comment: @André if you added this code, if replaced, but if you already have a tag `<? php` replaces me so `<? phpphp ...` and thus constantly.

Comment: @user3680708 good point, totally didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following sed command:

```
find -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/<?\([ \n]\|echo\)/<?php \1/g' {} \;
```

It is matching either a space or newline or the term `echo` after `<?` and then replaces it with `<?php<match_found>`

---

Note that you don't need the `xargs` call. You can simply use `find`'s `-exec` option. Also the `-e` option to `sed` is not necessary as long as you are using just a single expression. Also the `-type` criteria should be before the `-name` option. Otherwise find would throw a warning.

Comment: This works great, but do not understand its syntax, thank you very much!

Comment: It's a little bit advanced sed usage. Basically I'm working with a line buffer of two lines to be able to replace `<?<newline>` properly with `<?php<newline>`. The remaining part is almost the same as before but I escape most metacharacters with a \ because this is required with basic regulare expressions in sed

Comment: Still works find-type f-name "* php."-Exec sed-i 's / <\ ([\ n] \ | echo \) / <php \ 1 / g?' {} \;

Comment: find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/<?\([ \n]\|echo\)/<?php \1/g' --

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it with PHP:

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php

foreach (glob("./*.php") as $fn) {
    $data = file_get_contents($fn);
    $data = preg_replace("/<\?php/", "<?", $data);
    $data = preg_replace("/<\?[\b\n\s]*/", "<?php ", $data);

    file_put_contents("./$fn", $data);
}
```

Comment: Thank trick with php I do not like doing this kind of thing, but thank you friend!